# Can Ant-Man solve world hunger?

Tags: marvel, ant-man, plot-device

Can Pym Particles be used to take an ordinary apple, blow it up to the size of a building and feed an entire town?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97483/how-can-ant-man-ride-anthony?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe Pym particles change an objects size by increasing or decreasing the distance that the electrons orbit an atom's nucleus.

So there wouldn't be any more actual apple in the giant apple, though you would feel full after eating some.   The amount of nutrients would not be increased, so you would feel full while starving to death.

Comment: The comic version of [Pym Particles](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Pym_Particles) work differently, so that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Slightly undermined by that both the comics and movie allow the size change to sometimes change mass and sometimes not.

Comment: @Michael Richardson If it only changes the distance between the electrons and nuclei, how does Ant-man become so light when he shrinks (able to stand on arrows, guns and shoulders) and so heavy when he grows (topples over buildings when he falls)? He would have the same amount of mass regardless of size because of the number subatomic particles never change, right?

Comment: Handwavium.   At times he maintains his mass when he shrinks.   So the true answer would be:  It depends on the author and the needs of the story.

Comment: @Jamil It's called bad writing and writers not learning about the character before writing about them

Comment: Relevant: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96339/28010

Comment: Pym particles can do whatever the heck they want

Answer (score 3):

> Can Pym Particles be used to take an ordinary apple, blow it up to the size of a building and feed an entire town?

**Yes**, inferring from what is shown in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (emphasis mine):

> **Hank Pym:** [*Enlarges a small pizza to an extra-large pizza using Pym Particles*]
> I just saved eight bucks!

Hank, Janet, Hope, Scott, and Cassie then proceeded to eat the Pym Particle–enlarged pizza without any issues.

Video of the scene (relevant part starts at 00:32):

---

> Can Ant-Man solve world hunger?

Not yet, but Hope van Dyne is working on it.

> **Scott Lang:** [*talking about Hope van Dyne*] She's taken back her dad's company. Now **she's using Pym Particles for global change.** A lot of people say they want to save the world. But Hope? She saves it every day. Reforestation, affordable housing, **food production**. She's not wasting a second.

Comment: The food production might be from cheap enlarged greenhouses.  Food digestion is chemistry and unless there's more molecules the size won't be more food.  In fact it goes straight to the fact I believe the earlier movies made before the constant off/on cgi helmets- the oxygen supply needs to be the same size shift as the person breathing.